# Почему в телефоне на сайте недоступны поля ввода?

Tags: html, input, select

На сайте в телефонах и смартфонах в Google Chrome в режиме "Версия для ПК" на одной из страниц не доступны поля input и select. У них нет флага disabled или readonly. Но они не открываются: select'ы не раскрываются, а в input-полях на форме ничего нельзя вписать. Сайт сделан на Yii2. В чём может быть причина?

Вот код:

```
<?php
    $block_show = $OrderCheckoutHelper->getBlockDisplay('giving_order_point_1_block');
?>
<div class="row giving_order_point_1_block" style="display: <?php echo $OrderCheckoutHelper->getBlockDisplay('giving_order_point_1_block');?>;">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <?php echo $form->field($model, 'recipient_info[country_delivery]')
            ->dropDownList($countryOptions, ['prompt' => 'Страна', 'options' => $block_show == 'none' ? [] : $OrderCheckoutHelper->getActualFieldInfo('model', 'recipient_info', 'country_delivery', '[recipient_info][country_delivery]',true)['options']])
            ->label(false); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <?php echo $form->field($model, 'recipient_info[region_delivery]')
            ->textInput(['placeholder' => 'Регион/область', 'value' => $block_show == 'none' ? null : $OrderCheckoutHelper->getActualFieldInfo('model', 'recipient_info', 'region_delivery', '[recipient_info][region_delivery]')['value']])
            ->label(false); ?>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row giving_order_point_1_block" style="display: <?php echo $OrderCheckoutHelper->getBlockDisplay('giving_order_point_1_block');?>;">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <?php echo $form->field($model, 'recipient_info[city_delivery]')
            ->textInput(['placeholder' => 'Город/Населенный пункт', 'value' => $block_show == 'none' ? null : $OrderCheckoutHelper->getActualFieldInfo('model', 'recipient_info', 'city_delivery', '[recipient_info][city_delivery]')['value']])
            ->label(false); ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
    $block_show = $OrderCheckoutHelper->getBlockDisplay('giving_order_point_2_block');
?>
<div class="row giving_order_point_2_block" style="display: <?php echo $OrderCheckoutHelper->getBlockDisplay('giving_order_point_2_block');?>;">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <?php echo $form->field($model, 'recipient_info[street_delivery]')
            ->textInput(['placeholder' => 'Улица', 'value' => $block_show == 'none' ? null : $OrderCheckoutHelper->getActualFieldInfo('model', 'recipient_info', 'street_delivery', '[recipient_info][street_delivery]')['value']])
            ->label(false); ?>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row giving_order_point_2_block" style="display: <?php echo $OrderCheckoutHelper->getBlockDisplay('giving_order_point_2_block');?>;">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <?php echo $form->field($model, 'recipient_info[house_delivery]')
            ->textInput(['placeholder' => 'Дом', 'value' => $block_show == 'none' ? null : $OrderCheckoutHelper->getActualFieldInfo('model', 'recipient_info', 'house_delivery', '[recipient_info][house_delivery]')['value']])
            ->label(false); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <?php echo $form->field($model, 'recipient_info[flat_delivery]')
            ->textInput(['placeholder' => 'Квартира', 'value' => $block_show == 'none' ? null : $OrderCheckoutHelper->getActualFieldInfo('model', 'recipient_info', 'flat_delivery', '[recipient_info][flat_delivery]')['value']])
            ->label(false); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <?php echo $form->field($model, 'recipient_info[zip_delivery]')
            ->textInput(['placeholder' => 'Индекс', 'value' => $block_show == 'none' ? null : $OrderCheckoutHelper->getActualFieldInfo('model', 'recipient_info', 'zip_delivery', '[recipient_info][zip_delivery]')['value']])
            ->label(false); ?>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row to_terminal_city_block" style="display: <?php echo $OrderCheckoutHelper->getBlockDisplay('to_terminal_city_block');?>;">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <?php echo $form->field($model, 'shipping_company_delivery_city')
        ->textinput(['placeholder' => 'Город', 'value' => $OrderCheckoutHelper->getActualFieldInfo('model', 'shipping_company_delivery_city')['value']])
        ->label(false); ?>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="row address_delivery_block" style="display: <?php echo $OrderCheckoutHelper->getBlockDisplay('address_delivery_block');?>;">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <?php echo $form->field($model, 'recipient_info[address_delivery]')
        ->textInput(['placeholder' => 'Пункт выдачи заказов', 'value' => $OrderCheckoutHelper->getActualFieldInfo('model', 'recipient_info', 'address_delivery', '[address_delivery]')['value']])
        ->label(false); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Заменил `col-sm-6` и `col-sm-12` на соответствующие `col-md-6` и `col-md-12` и всё заработало.